# Yarn Custom Bootstrap installation config.json

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, yarnpkg

I want to install with Yarn a lighter version of bootstrap but using "yarn add boostrap" there is not way to pass a config.json file. How can I do it?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/

https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right you want to install a customized (lighter) bootstrap version you created according to: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/ or using a customizer tool.
Then use this command:

```
yarn add file:/path/to/local/folder
```

installs a package that is on your local file system. 
The command

```
yarn add bootstrap
```

loads the precompiled version from the repo. so in your case the steps are:

- Create customized bootstrap

  - Compile locally yourself OR
  - use online tool and download YOUR Bootstrap version
- save package to a local folder in your project/ dev environment
- add via yarn add file:/path/to/local/folder
- Read more on adding packages: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add/